# PYPLOT Defining a marker shape in Python with a variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

So an exemplar format would be:

```py
plt.plot([1],[1],'rs')
```

In this circumstance the marker would be a red square, however, I'm not sure how to do this with a defined variable (ex: `markershape = 's'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for this and it's pretty simple and easy too.

```
>>> markershape = 's'
>>> plt.plot(np.arange(10), f'r{markershape}')
```

[image]

In fact you can do it with most of the stuff. Like with color and markershape as well:

```
>>> color = 'g'
>>> markershape = 'v'

>>> plt.plot(np.arange(10), f'{color}{markershape}')
```

[image]